# Vuetify Navigation Drawer - bind selected item to to Vue v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am looking to bind the navigation drawer to the v-model in vue/vuetify.

I was able to do this easily using the radio group (`v-radio-group`  - see below)

```
v-radio-group v-model="selectedList" :mandatory="false"
```

But would prefer to use the navigation drawer for visual reasons.  Is there a way to bind in similar way or another solution?  Thanks you.

Comment: What are you expecting the v-model to do with the Navigation Drawer?

Comment: all I want the navigation drawer to do is set a variable so I can conditionally flip templates based on the user's selection.  I could do this with tabs but there are no vertical tabs.  I accomplished what I want with radio group but it is ugly - would prefer to use the navigation drawer

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in an example for the v-stepper.  On each level of the navigation drawer -just add below to click event and I get what I needed.  SelectedItem is variable in vue data and item.icon is the value that was originally put in each navigation drawer.

@click="selectedItem = item.icon"

thanks to all for weighing in.